# How to well-employ undocument templated class?

Tags: c++, class, templates, non-type

I would like to employ a templated class from libff C++ library.

This class requires two non-type arguments, :

```
template<mp_size_t n, const bigint<n>& modulus>
class Fp_model;
```

I employ the following snippet where `wrong_modulus` has type `libff::bigint<4l>`

```
        using namespace libff;
        const mp_size_t limbs = 4;
        bigint<limbs> wrong_modulus="21888242871839275222246405745257275088548364400416034343698204186575808495617";
        const bigint<limbs> & ref_modulus= wrong_modulus;
        Fp_model<limbs, ref_modulus)> element;
```

It leads to the error message:

```
error: the value of ‘ref_modulus’ is not usable in a constant expression Fp_model<limbs, ref_modulus)> element;
```

Have you ideas to explain why it is not possible to employ `ref_modulus` in this situation and how to remediate it?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Local object refs cannot be template arguments.

Comment: Is the declaration of `element` inside a function or is it global?